# Markov Process, holding times are exponential

Tags: stochastic-processes, exponential-function, markov-chains

im  looking at the holding times for a markov process where c(.,.) are the transition rates. My question comes at the end of this working, can you explain when the sentance at the end means? I get that this quality (product to sum) holds for the exponential function but is it unique to the exponential function?

Let

$$\tau_{x}:=\inf\{t\geq 0 \hspace{1.5mm} : \hspace{1.5mm} \omega_{t} \neq x \}$$

then if $\sum_{y\in \Omega}c(x,y)>0$ it turns out that $\tau_{x}\sim Exp(\sum_{y\in \Omega}c(x,y)) $. Proof:\

Since our process is Markov it only cares about its current state and not how much time it has spent in its current state. i.e the holding time $\tau$ has the 'loss of memory property $$P^{x}(\tau_{x}>s+t \hspace{1.5mm} | \hspace{1.5mm} \tau_{x}>s)=P^{x}(\tau_{x}>s+t \hspace{1.5mm} | \hspace{1.5mm} \omega_{s}=x)=P^{x}(\tau_{x}>t).$$

Hence
$$P^{x}(\tau_{x}>s+t)=P^{x}(\tau_{x}>s+t|\tau_{x}>s)P^{x}(\tau_{x}>s)=P^{x}(\tau_{x}>t)\cdot P^{x}(\tau_{x}>s)$$

????
Then this is the functional equation for the exponential and implies that $P^{x}(\tau_{x}>t)=e^{\lambda t}$
????

Comment: Let $g(t) = P^X(\tau_x > t)$. The last inequality implies $g(t+s) = g(t)g(s)$ for all $s,t\geqslant 0$. This implies that $g$ is identically zero (which is impossible since  $\tau_x$ is finite a.s.) or $g(t) = e^{\lambda t}$ for some real $\lambda$.

Comment: inequality? you mean equality. why is it zero or e ? are there no other functions for which g(t+s)=g(t)g(s) holds?